# How to convert Set<Set<String>> to Set<String>?

Tags: java, stream, set

Assuming that Streams and Collections, Lambdas are allowed to use?
I tried using a for loop but it didn't solve my problem.

```java
// Set<Set<String>> to Set<String>
for(Set<String> s : set) {
    result.addAll(s);
    set.add(result);
}
```

set is a `Set<Set<String>>` type and result is a type of `Set<String>`.

Comment: Why do you add `result` back to `set`, repeatedly?

Comment: Why are you using the statement `set.add(result);`

Comment: If you take out `set.add(result);`, your code would be correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the option using Stream API:

```
Set<String> result = sets.stream()
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: It would be better to use `flatMap(Set::stream)` as it more specifically means the input is a `Set`

Comment: @GauthamM That’s a matter of taste. The method is declared in the `Collection` interface, so we need not know or care whether it’s `Set` or something else. I would probably do it the way you say, but I have no argument why it should be better or worse.